# How to get id from Spinner and it is populated by database

Tags: android, android-spinner

I create a `Spinner` by populating it by a local database.
In my DBHelper I used `List<String>`

```
public List<String> getServices(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TBL_SERVICES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
```

In my fragment I use this to load up my spinner

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {

    initialazeDatabase();

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = dbHelper.getServices();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spn_services.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

then after that I was trying to get the ID of it but I only get the position not the ID from the database

```
spn_services.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {
           Log.e(TAG, "My service id is " + pos + "My Id is "+ id);

        }
```

id is just returning the same value of what pos have. How can I get the rowID that is save from the database?

**

I only have 2 column in my services table its id and services_name.

I debug it and saw this

[image: debug result]

it only gets my String and not my rowID in the database because my database looks like this

[image]

Comment: Can you post your database schema?  It would be helpful to know what the are the columns in your TBL_SERVICES table.

Comment: @EJK i only have two columns inside my services table id and services_name

Comment: Have you confirmed that the List<String> returned by your getServices() method contains the expected values?

Comment: By checking what my emulator is displaying it display all my services_name. @EJK

Comment: OK, but that is not what I am asking.  I was asking about the contents of the array.  Were you able to view the array in a debugger?  If not, could you at least put in some Log statements to dump the contents of the array to LogCat?  That would help determine if the problem is in the data retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the rowid by changing your query:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT rowid, * FROM " + TBL_SERVICES;
```

But then the problem is that you can't use `ArrayAdapter`.

`ArrayAdapter` will *always* use the position as the id.  Since you are getting the id from the database, the correct solution for you is a subclass of `CursorAdapter`.  In your case, you can use `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

So let's change your `dbHelper` `getServices()` method to return a `Cursor`:

```
    public Cursor getServicesCursor() {

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT rowid AS _id, * FROM " + TBL_SERVICES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    }
```

The docs for `CursorAdapter` say

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

so we rename "rowid" to "_id" in the query.

Then it's simple:

```
    private void loadSpinnerData() {

        initialazeDatabase();

        // Spinner Drop down cursor
        Cursor servicesCursor = dbHelper.getServicesCursor();

        // map the cursor column names to the TextView ids in the layout
        String[] from = { "services_name" };
        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
              servicesCursor, from, to, 0);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spn_services.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to create my own Adapter for extending the BaseAdapter?

Comment: Actually, I wasn't thinking -- there is a simpler and more obvious solution; I updated my answer.  Cheers

Comment: this solved all my issues of populate from DB to spinner with their ID! thank you. =)